# How to select multiple column names (not values) in a table when column value is specified-Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has around 30 columns.Out of 30 columns i need to retrieve around 25 column names where value is set to some specified value(say 1).

I am not able to find a way to do this.Will multiple if statement work as below

```
select if columnname1='1' then 'columnname1' else null 
  if columnname2='1' then 'columnname2' else null  from table.
```

In case the value is not set to 1, i don't want to retrieve the column names.

The below query can give me the column names but i can't specify the value with below query
select DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='table_name'.

Comment: I think you have this backward, because the way you have it written, when the value is not 1 then you will retrieve the column names. Also, why did you tag MySQL if you are using Oracle?

Comment: i have removed the tag of mysql.Yes i have ..will change it now

Comment: What is not working about my answer?  What values do you expect to see? Help us help you with some more details

Comment: Hi Kevin, i wanted to retrieve the column names(not values) where the value is set to 1.In your answer INSTR function is not working for me.I tried using decode function to get the column names if value is set to 1 and then unpivot to get them in vertical order.The decode and unpivot are of help but sql becomes quite big as i have to specify all the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

> SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
>   from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
>   where TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'
>   AND INSTR(column_name,'1') >0